# POST XmlHttpRequest not work

Tags: xmlhttprequest, smartface.io

I have tried a lot but cannot make POST send through XMLHttpRequest
this it the code

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var params="device=android&device_token="+Notifications.remote.token"
xhr.open("POST", "https://xxx.xxx.it/test.php",true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Access_Token", "11bdf06b9fda0639b300c023cb0b3ba5");
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xhr.send(params);
```

Page is called but nothing is passed.. no Access_Token and no POST values

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Desktop version, you can't do this way. You have to use WebClient class, I couldn't find the desktop documentation because Smartface has updated to Cloud and deleted it (or at least hidden it), sorry. But there's another question on Stack Overflow that I explain how to use Firebase with Smartface, I recommend reading it for better understanding. 
[How to create a webservice for a login system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387805/how-to-create-a-webservice-for-a-login-system)

Hope that helps! :)